# Total differential related limit

Tags: limits, derivatives

I am trying to find whether total differential of $u(x,y)=y^{1/3}\arctan x$ exists at $(0,0)$, where partial derivatives are zero, so I want to know if $$\lim_{(h_1,h_2)\to\vec 0} \frac{{h_2}^{1/3}\arctan h_1}{||\vec h||}=0$$. According to Wolfram, the limit doesn't exist. Could you please give a hint on how to prove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $arctan h_1\approx h_1$ as $h_1$ is small.

So $|\frac{{h_2}^{1/3}\arctan h_1}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}|\le c|\frac{{h_2}^{1/3}h_1}{h_1}|\to 0$ as $(h_1,h_2)\to (0,0)$